# Northwind OData service Not Availbe?

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-platform, sap-web-ide

Trying to use *Northwind oData Service* but not data is returned, previously this was working.

when I check the connection I get the following message:

> Connection to "Northwind" established. Response returned: "301: Moved
>   Permanently"

Any suggestions on how to resolve greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I just faced a similar situation right now.

Most likely you are using the link without the secure protocol.

Try using `https://services.odata.org` instead of `http://services.odata.org`.

I saw old configurations pointing to the wrong URL, but after changing to the secure protocol the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check out the URL :

https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata

NorthWind ODATA Service is working

https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Categories?$format=json.